# How to validate multiple Google reCAPTCHA in same page

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, recaptcha

How to validate multiple Google reCAPTCHA  in same page with javascript. I already try with some online code but it's not working properly.

**Code I use **

```
<script>
document.getElementById("footer_form").addEventListener("submit",function(evt)
  {
  
  var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if(response.length == 0) 
  { 
    //reCaptcha not verified
    alert("please verify you are humann!"); 
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //captcha verified
  //do the rest of your validations here
  
});
</script>

<script>
    document.getElementById("popup_form") .addEventListener("submit",function(evt)
    {
  
  var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if(response.length == 0) 
  { 
      
    //reCaptcha not verified

    alert("please verify you are humann!"); 
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }
  //captcha verified
  //do the rest of your validations here
  
});
</script>
```